# Passing in data from Mongodb to HTML table using javascript using Node.js framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, mongodb

I'm quite new at using node.js. Right now I'm trying to pull data from MongoDB and display it in a table using Javascript + HTML. However, my table is populating with undefined in all the fields. I think something is definitely wrong with how I'm reading data through to the Javascript function b/c I am able to render the full results from the people.js file straight to the webpage. Thank you in advance!! Below is my code:

Code for my people.js file:

```
exports.getPeople = (req, res) => {
  People.find((err, docs) => {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (docs != null){
     console.log(docs.length)
     docs.forEach(function(docs, index) {
     console.log(index + " key: " + docs.name)
       });
     res.render('people', { people: docs });
    }
   else{
    res.render('people', { people: docs() });
   }
 });
};
```

My Javascript + HTML that's populating my webpage.

```
  script(type='text/javascript', src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js', charset='UTF-8')
  script.
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var obj=  '$(people)'

      var tbl = "<table>"
      var content="";
      for(i=0; i<obj.length;i++){
        content +=
          '<tr>+<td>' +obj[i]["name"]+
          '</td><td>'+obj[i]["type"]+
          '</td><td>'+obj[i]["min_hours"]+
          '</td><td>'+obj[i]["max_hours"]+
          '</td><td>'+obj[i]["email"]+
          '</td><td>'+obj[i]["phone_number"]+
          '</td><td>'+ '<input type="button" value = "Update" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">' +
          '</td><td>'+'<input type="button" value = "Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">';
          '</td></tr>';
        }
      content += "</table>"
      $('#myTableData').append(content);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, you can render the array results from the `people.js` file directly into the webpage. So, you don't have to read the data through a JavaScript function using jQuery. The template engine language is built on top of JavaScript and it supports plenty of methods and features to do what you're trying to achieve here. So, for example, you may use an iteration method like `each..in` to build your table (see docs - [Iteration](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html)):

```js
// ...

body
      table(id="myTableData")

        // for each person in the people array (from people.js) ...

        each person in people 

          // build a new table row
          tr 

            // insert table data
            td #{person.name}
            td #{person.type}
            td #{person.min_hours}
            td #{person.max_hours}
            td #{person.email}
            td #{person.phone_number}

            // add the update and delete buttons
            td 
              input(type="button" value = "Update" onclick=" ... ")
              input(type="button" value = "Delete" onclick=" ... ")

            // move to next person in the people array ...
```

**The Problem**

`var obj = '$(people)'` does not work as you may expect. You want `obj` to hold the `people` array from the `people.js` file so that you can loop over each object in the array, but this is not what's happening. `obj` is actually a string value of length 9, so the `for` loop evaluates 9 string values (not objects). This is why all of your fields are `undefined`.

To see what I mean, run this code snippet:

```js
var obj = '$(people)';

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){

  console.log(obj[i]);
  console.log(obj[i]["name"]);
  
}
```

The reason `$(people)` does not evaluate to an object is mainly because the parent element, `script.` causes everything below it to evaluate to plain text. The `.` after the tag causes the template engine to render plain text (see docs: [Block in a Tag](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html)).

If you wanted to assign `people` to `obj` in your inline script you may try it this way:

```js
script
  | var obj = #{people};
```

But this will cause an `Unexpected identifier` JavaScript error because of the `_id` field on each item in `people`. By default `_id` is an ObjectID hex value from MongoDb so you would have to either remove the `_id` field from the `docs` or add quotes to each `doc._id` so it evaluates to a string. This would all have to be done in `person.js` before you return the data.

To see what I mean about the `Unexpected identifier` error, run this code snippet:

```js
// works
var obj = { _id: '583ab33cdaf857b543c76afe',
  name: 'john'};

// Error: Unexpected identifier
var obj = { _id: 583ab33cdaf857b543c76afe,
  name: 'john'};
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Literally have been trying to figure this out for hours last night, and you saved me hours of trying to do this again. I went with iterating through people via the pug file, way less messy and really straight forward.